# Python Web Scrapping: Get html links from within a specific Div and from sub pages also

Tags: python, html

I need to scrape datafrom a link. The required data is hidden within another link on the webpage.
Something similar to the webpage I am working is this link - [College List](https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/). Say I need to get data about each college listed in this site. First, I land on this page. Then I extract all relevant links on this page and subsequent other pages. Then I go to each link and get relevant data.

I am not able to get the desired list of links and how to go to next page and do the same thing?

What I have tried so far is -

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

url = 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnl_collegelist"]/ul/li[1]')

col=[]
for t in tr_elements[0]: # starting from 2nd row for column headers
    name=t.text_content()
    col.append(name)

print(col) #gives me string values and not links
print(tr_elements[0].xpath('//a/@href')) # Gives me all links. I need links within Div [@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pnl_collegelist"] only.
```

I am not able to get the required link list by page. I think there are some 2K+ pages in this site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `beautiful soup` to scrape the site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

url = f"https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/"

print(f"Scraping {url} ...")

page = requests.get(url)
page.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("div", class_="clg-lists").find("ul")
assert table, "table not found"

for item in table.find_all("a", href=True):
    data.append({
        "link": item["href"],
        "text": item.text.strip(),
    })
print(data)

# Returns in format
# [
#     {
#         "link": "https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/iifa-lancaster-degree-college-bangalore.aspx",
#         "text": "IIFA Lancaster Degree College, Bangalore\n#5,14/2,Suvarna Jyothi Layout,\xa0Jnanabharathi post, Nagadevanahalli, Bangalore - Karnataka, India\nPhone : +91 9845984211,+91 7349241005, Landline No:08023241999",
#     }, {
#         "link": "https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/iifa-multimedia-bangalore.aspx",
#         "text": "IIFA Multimedia, Bangalore\n#262 80 feet main road srinivasa nagar,\xa09th main corner, Bangalore - Karnataka, India\nPhone : 080 48659176, +91 7349241004,+91 9845006824",
#     },
#     ...
# ]
```

Outputs:

```
Scraping https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/ ...
[{'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/iifa-lancaster-degree-college-bangalore.aspx', 'text': 'IIFA Lancaster Degree College, Bangalore\n#5,14/2,Suvarna Jyothi Layout,\xa0Jnanabharathi post, Nagadevanahalli, Bangalore - Karnataka, India\nPhone : +91 9845984211,+91 7349241005, Landline No:08023241999'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/iifa-multimedia-bangalore.aspx', 'text': 'IIFA Multimedia, Bangalore\n#262 80 feet main road srinivasa nagar,\xa09th main corner, Bangalore - Karnataka, India\nPhone : 080 48659176, +91 7349241004,+91 9845006824'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/3-berhampur-college-berhampur.aspx', 'text': '+3 Berhampur College, Berhampur\nRaj Berhampur Berhampur - Orissa, India\nPhone : N/A'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/3-panchayat-samiti-mahavidyalaya-balangir.aspx', 'text': '+3 Panchayat Samiti Mahavidyalaya, Balangir\nGyana Vihar  Deogaon Balangir - Orissa, India\nPhone : N/A'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/21st-century-international-school-trust-sivagangai.aspx', 'text': '21St Century International School Trust, Sivagangai\nRani Velu Nachiar Nagar, Kangirangal Post, Sivagangai Sivagangai - Tamil Nadu, India\nPhone : 04575 - 244930'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/3dfx-animation-school-kochi.aspx', 'text': '3DFX Animation School, Kochi\nNear MP Office, Kattuparambil Towers, Old Market Road, Angamaly, Kochi - Kerala, India\nPhone : 91 0484 2455799'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/4-g-fire-college-sonipat.aspx', 'text': '4 G Fire College, Sonipat\nK.C. Plaza, 1ST FLOWER,Above Eye Q Hospita , Atlas Road, Near State Bank of India, Sonipat - Haryana, India\nPhone : 9466769467, 7206220706'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/5-gates-multimedia-solutions-indore.aspx', 'text': '5 Gates Multimedia Solutions, Indore\n102 Krtgya Tower, 8, Janki Nagar, A.b. Road, Indore - Madhya Pradesh, India\nPhone : (0731) 2400656'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/a-a-arts-and-science-college-chennai.aspx', 'text': 'A A Arts And Science College, Chennai\n42/1, Srinivasan Nagar, Iind Street, Koyambedu Chennai - Tamil Nadu, India\nPhone : 044-28553109, 28526202'}, {'link': 'https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/a-a-govt-arts-college-attur-salem.aspx', 'text': 'A A Govt Arts College Attur, Salem\nSalem Salem - Tamil Nadu, India\nPhone : N/A'}]
```

If you want to scrape all of the 2k+ pages, you need to use `multithreading` to scrape site faster. I used the code on [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/faster-web-scraping-in-python-using-multithreading-496da9eaf0c2). Don't forget to replace variale `NUM_THREADS` with your number of threads. I highly recommend to writing the output into a file while the program is scraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures
import time

# REPLACE WITH YOUR NUMBER OF THREADS
NUM_THREADS = 8

links = [f"https://www.indiacollegeshub.com/colleges/page-{index}.aspx" for index in range(1, 2480)] # 1 - 2479

data = []

def scrape(url):
    print(f"Scraping {url} ...")

    page = requests.get(url)
    page.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find("div", class_="clg-lists").find("ul")
    assert table, "table not found"

    for item in table.find_all("a", href=True):
        data.append({
            "link": item["href"],
            "text": item.text.strip(),
        })

start_time = time.time()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS) as executor:
    executor.map(scrape, links)

total_time = time.time() - start_time

print(total_time)
```